# How to calculate x^3 mod n = 427

Tags: cryptography

I got a message: 427, this message will be signed with RSA key, but only the public part of the RSA key is available so KeyPub:(N=3901, e = 3).
To my knowledge 427 would get signed with d, so the multiplicative inverse of 3 modulo 3901 = 2601.

My solution is (calculated by Wolframalpha):

$427^{2601}(mod \thinspace 3901) = 1614$

**BUT**

$1614^3 mod \thinspace3901 = 853$
So if am not misstaken there must be an error, as I was expecting 427

Goal: To find a, the signed version of 427, y such that: $$y^e (mod \thinspace3901) = 427 (mod \thinspace 3901), \text{for}  \space e =3$$

To solve I got my "basic" calculator and a table of the multiplicative inverses in mod 3901 like. Factoring the public key is not possible by the task description.

| x | x^(-1) |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2601 |
| 114 | 1403 |
| 427 | 3161 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you computed $d\equiv 3^{-1}\mod N$, but it should be  modulo $\phi(N)$ instead, where $\phi$ is the [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Here, we have $N = 3901 = 47\cdot 83$, so $\phi(N) = 46\cdot 82 = 3772$ and $d = 2515$. Checking, we have $(427^3)^{2515}\equiv 427\mod 3901$.

This is also why RSA was secure - you have to factor $N$ to compute the private key $d$, and factoring was hard.

Comment: "Was" secure? It is still in common use today. You just use slightly bigger primes.

Comment: @Arthur Shor's algorithm breaks it quantum'ly and we should move away from it, even though it might be decades later.

Comment: I totally understand your answer, thanks! But isn't this factorisation of the public key? Is there a way to do this without it, whilst using the multiplicative inverse x^-1 of mod N?

Comment: Actually,  the shortest private key is $629$ thanks to [the Carmichael Function as $\lambda$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87585/18298)